# How to ensure calling onkeyup event only once

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to append a html tag for an 'onkeyup' event. But I need to have it do it only on the first keyup event.

```
<label for="url">Add URL of your webpage:</label> 
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="" placeholder="Optional" onkeyup="addlink();"/>
```

I am using jquery append() function to achieve it. I am not able to find a solution on how to make sure that the event gets fired only on the first keyup. And does not get fired after that. Also if all the content from the text input is deleted I want the remove what I have appended. 
Is there any way to achieve it. I hope I have explained myself.

Comment: can you show us the jquery, specifically the `addlink()` function?

Comment: @JustAnil: the code for the addlink() function:  
function addlink(){       $('#wiframe').contents().find('#aboutHeading').append('<br><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Go to Home Page</a>');
  $('#url').unbind('onkeyup', false);
 }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following code it will help

```
$('#url').one("keyup", function(){
   addLink();
});
```

the jQuery `one()` event fires only once for the given element

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the event handler from running more than once, you can use jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method or [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) depending on which is more suitable for your case.